# Regarding Activity.getApplicationContext()

Tags: android

I have created a custom adapter for a list view. In the constructor of the adapter i do the following:

```
public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<CatalogueItemListData> items,int width) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.context =context;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }
```

In my activity class i call the adaper as below:

```
this.m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_orders,displayMetrics.widthPixels);
            listView.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

and i get the output as in the image below:
[image: Output when context is passed to the constructor]

Now when i change the constructor of my adapter as below:

```
 public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<CatalogueItemListData> items,int width) {
    super(activity.getApplicationContext(), textViewResourceId, items);
    this.context =activity.getApplicationContext();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }
```

I get the following output:

[image: Output when using activity.getApplicationContext()]

Could someone kindly tell me what could be the possible reason for the difference in the outputs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, activity is context itself, and it may differ from your application context. but why is it differ in your cause ... Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have applied a different theme to your specific activity then the entire application. This could cause the difference in styles based on which context is used. I am not sure if this is what is happening but it would make sense.

Comment: Hi, I am not using any theme in my application or doing changes with respect to this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your application context will use previously defined theme (or default theme) where was your activity context will not unless you call it explicitly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Could you kindly tell me what "where as your activity context will not unless you call it explicitly." mean?

Comment: So the right way of doing would be to call activity.getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Either is fine, just be aware that getApplicationContext will inherit the theme set in your Android manifest (or the default theme).